# IEでしか機能しない在庫システムがあるのはなぜですか？

Tags: java, internet-explorer

電帳法などの対応で、既存の在庫システムを見直す必要にせまられています。
そのときふと思ったのは、IEでしかただしく機能しない在庫システムなどがあるのはどうしてなのかとということです。
とくにJAVAベースのシステムなどでそういう仕様にたびたび出会った記憶があります。
事情にくわしいかたがおられたらご教示ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorerを残して、各WebブラウザーはJavaサポートを終了しています。「JAVAベースのシステム」が動作しないのも当然かと。

[ChromeはNPAPI (Javaアプレットに必要な技術)をサポートしなくなりました](https://www.java.com/ja/download/help/chrome.html)

> Webブラウザ用のJavaプラグインは、クロス・プラットフォーム型のプラグイン・アーキテクチャであるNPAPIを利用しています。このNPAPIは、すべての主要Webブラウザで10年間にわたってサポートされてきました。GoogleのChromeバージョン45 (2015年9月にリリース予定)ではNPAPIのサポートが廃止されます。これはSilverlight、Java、Facebook Videoおよび他の同様のNPAPIベースのプラグインに影響を与えます。

[Java、Silverlight、Adobe Acrobat および他のプラグインが動作しなくなりました](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/npapi-plugins)

> 2017 年 3 月 7 日にリリースされた Firefox バージョン 52 以降、Adobe Flash Player を除き Firefox は NPAPI プラグイン をサポートしていません。これらのプラグインがコンピューター上にインストールされていても Java や Microsoft Silverlight、Adobe Acrobat を含め、Firefox に読み込まれなくなります。

Comment: 引用URLなども添えていただき、技術的な理解ができました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

結論から言うと

- IEでしか動作確認されていないから
- IEでしかサポートされない機能を利用しているから

でしょう。

2000年以前、日本国内のブラウザはIEが事実上の標準だったため、それ以外のブラウザでは動作確認されていないことがほとんどでした。特に在庫管理システムのような、社内でしか利用されないような環境の場合、会社標準としてIEを使うことになっていれば、それ以外のブラウザに対応する必要性はありませんでした。
（しかし現状は、Chromeがブラウザが台頭し、iPhoneはSafari、WindowsでもEdgeと、IE以外のブラウザが利用されることが当たり前の時代になっています。）

また1990年代から2010年頃までに構築されたWebシステムのサーバ側アプリケーションはJavaが使用されていることが多いです。当時はまだWeb標準（HTML,CSS,JavaScript）が未熟で、複雑な機能はJavaアプレットという技術を使って実装されることもありました。現状JavaアプレットがサポートされるのはIEのみかと思います。

それ以外にもIEは表示（見た目）を制御するCSSに多くのバグを抱えており、IEで正しく表示されていても他のブラウザでは不正となることもしばしばありますし、JavaScriptもIE独自の機能があり、それを使用して構築した場合、他のブラウザては動作しません。

IE以外のブラウザが次々とAdobe Flashのサポートを打ち切っているのは、それが不要となるほどWeb標準が進化しブラウザの実装が進んだことを意味しますが、IEに関しては進化がかなり遅かった、という状況でした。

Comment: 技術経緯がとてもよく理解できました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

「IEでしか」というよりも「Windowsでしか」機能しないというのが本当だと思われます。

そして「在庫システム」に限らずシステムというものは企画・設計・開発・テスト・運用・保守・更新といったライフサイクルの全てにおいて多くの人員・機器・時間・コストといったリソースを必要とします。

そのシステムの中に動作を保証する「何かの要素」が1つ増えるだけでも必要なリソースの量が跳ね上がります。
そのため、動作対象の範囲を限定するのは普通に行われます。

「とくにJAVAベースのシステムなど」というのも偶々でしょう。

システムの見直し時期に来ているということは、長く運用されてきたものでしょうから、それが企画・設計された時期の事情で決まったのだと考えられます。
詳細にするとか視点を変えるとかすれば他にも色々とあるでしょうが、大まかには下記のような事だと考えられます。

一番目は当時の「IE」や「Windows」でしか動作しないか、それ以外でも動作させるには多大なリソースを必要とする「何か」が前提条件や必要事項に入っていた、というものです。

二番目は当時のブラウザ間の互換性・相互運用性が低かったであろうことと、一番目と関係して複数種類のブラウザ/OSをサポートするという発想そのものが無かったと思われます。

Comment: システムは作って終わりではなく、その後の長い運用というコストが必要だと感じています。今後の計画に生かしていきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。